# getting last element in last line using php and pass it to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

By clicking on each button I am sending a variable to php and from there I save it in a txt file:

```
submitInfo(var1);
Tabs.prototype.submitInfo = function(var1)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "js/info.php", 
        data: {var2:var1}
    });
};
```

and in php:

```
<?php
    $varToSend = '';
    $filename = 'test.txt';

    if (isset($_POST['var2']))
    {
        $sentHashArray = $_POST['var2'].PHP_EOL;
    }

    file_put_contents($filename, $varToSend , FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

and this is a sample test.txt I get:

```
A
B
C
D
```

now how can I get the last element from test.txt (D) using php and pass it to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one to get value `D`:

```
$data = explode('<br>',nl2br(file_get_contents($yourFile),false));
echo $data[count($data)-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific "get last line" function. A quick/dirty workaround is

```
$last_line = array_pop(file('test.txt'));
```

But if your file gets very large, this will be inefficient - it'll force PHP to parse the entire file into an array in memory, only to strip off the last array element and throw away everything else.

For large files, you'd be better off simply opening the file and scanning backwards from the end for the first linebreak/eol-type char you encounter.